# How do I determine if a string is not a regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to improve the performance of some code. It looks something like this:

```
public boolean isImportant(String token) {
    for (Pattern pattern : patterns) {
        return pattern.matches(token).find();
    }
}
```

What I noticed is that many of the Patterns seem to be simple string literals with no regular expression constructs. So I want to simply store these in a separate list (importantList) and do an equality test instead of performing a more expensive pattern match, such as follows:

```
public boolean isImportant(String token) {
    if (importantList.contains(token)) return true;

    for (Pattern pattern : patterns) {
        return pattern.matches(token).find();
    }        
}
```

How do I programmatically determine if a particular string contains no regular expression constructs?

Edit:
I should add that the answer doesn't need to be performance-sensitive. (i.e. regular expressions can be used) I'm mainly concerned with the performance of isImportant() because it's called millions of times, while the initialzation of the patterns is only done once.

Comment: Wouldn't doing a regular expression on a string to determine if it's a regular expression every time be much worse than just using each string as a regular expression?

Comment: @MikeM: That's not what he's asking. `hello` is a perfectly valid regex.

Comment: Not possible (atleast not easy or worthwhile, unless you find some pattern in plain string literals). A simple string literal is a valid regex pattern.

Comment: Consider what `Pattern`s you are using. If they have special characters, put them in `patterns`, otherwise put their literal in `importantList`.

Comment: I bet doing a list lookup every time for every string (especially if that list gets to be long) is going to hurt your performance *much*  more than a regex match (which is highly optimized. You'd be surprised).

Comment: if you are bent on doing this, I would make sure importantList isn't a list at all, but is something like a HashSet so the contains call is as inexpensive as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's going to be difficult. You can check for the non-presence of any regex metacharacters; that should be a good approximation:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[$^()\\[\\]{}.*+?\\\\]");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
regexIsLikely = regexMatcher.find();
```

Whether it's worth it is another question. Are you sure a regex match is slower than a list lookup (especially since you'll be doing a regex match after that in many cases anyway)? I'd bet it's much faster to just keep the regex match.

Comment: This is the solution I went with. Interestingly enough, I cut processing time by about 50%.

Answer (score 4):

I normally hate answers that say this but...

Don't do that.

It probably won't make the code run faster, in fact it might even cause the program to take more time.

if you really need to optimize your code, there are likely much mush much more effective places where you can go.

Comment: I intend for the profiler to answer the question of whether or not the optimizations are meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to determine it as every regex pattern is nothing else than a string. Furthermore there is nearly no performance difference as regex is smart nowadays and I'm pretty sure, if the pattern and source lengths are the same, equity check is the first that will be done

Comment: It depends, but I would estimate that Java attempts to do the much more efficient DFA regex first and only swaps to NFA if the expression requires it (such as if it includes lookaround)

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong

```
    for (Pattern pattern : patterns)
```

you should create one big regex that ORs all patterns; then for each input you only match once.

Comment: Thanks. I actually did that and it turned out that using one giant pattern was about 1/3 faster than matching against multiple small patterns.